# Azure CLI storage delete-batch with exclude pattern

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli

Consider this list of blobs (or any storage data):

```
backup-2018-08-29-0000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0300.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0400.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0500.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0600.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0700.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0800.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0900.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1300.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1400.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1500.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1600.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1700.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1800.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1900.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2300.archive
```

I wish to delete all files except one. So my initial idea is to use **--pattern** flag.

> --pattern
>
> The pattern used for globbing files or blobs in the source. The
>   supported patterns are '*', '?', '[seq]', and '[!seq]'.
>
> [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-delete-batch)

But I can not find info about how '*', '?', '[seq]', and '[!seq]' works.

In the command below, what pattern will seize all files excluding `backup-2018-08-29-0000.archive`?

```
$ az storage blob delete-batch --source mycontainer --pattern <pattern>
```

### Update

Additional issue is that I have about 10000 backups collected in more than one year. Using non-batch operations seems non practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by doing two batch-delete commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING has taken from env
CONTAINER=backups
DATES="201[78]-??-??"

# delete blobs with a range of 1000-2300 timestamps    
az storage blob delete-batch \
  --connection-string $AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING \
  --source $CONTAINER \
  --pattern "$DATES-[1-2][0-9]00--mongo.archive"

# delete blobs with a range of 0100-0900 timestamps
az storage blob delete-batch \
  --connection-string $AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING \
  --source $CONTAINER \
  --pattern "$DATES-0[1-9]00--mongo.archive"
```

With this script, I'm deleting all backups excluding backups made at midnight (with `0000` timestamp).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is an easy way to do that with wildcards (it would be easy with regex). 
`[seq]` and `[!seq]` works like that:

```
--pattern backup-2018-08-29-[01]???.archive
```

would delete all with files where the first digit after `29-` is either `0` or `1`:

```
backup-2018-08-29-0000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0300.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0400.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0500.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0600.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0700.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0800.archive
backup-2018-08-29-0900.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1300.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1400.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1500.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1600.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1700.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1800.archive
backup-2018-08-29-1900.archive
```

[!seq] just negates that:

```
--pattern backup-2018-08-29-[!01]???.archive
```

This would delete:

```
backup-2018-08-29-2000.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2100.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2200.archive
backup-2018-08-29-2300.archive
```

---

To answer your question. I would rename (copy) the blob to e.g. backup-keep.archive and then delete the remaining backups using the pattern `backup-2018-08-29-????.archive`

Comment: So the `?` sign is an single any character and then `*` is for one or more of any characters. For example this pattern `backup-2018-08-??-0000.archive` will match all blobs with time `0000` in any day within `08` month and pattern `backup*.archive` will match any files that starts with `backup` and  `.archive` extension?

Comment: This appears to be the only place on the internet where `[seq]` and `[!seq]` are documented!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Acquire lease` of the blob(in the portal or use [`az storage blob lease acquire`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-lease-acquire)
), then use the command `az storage blob delete-batch` to delete other blobs. If you lease the blob, the blob could not be deleted, if you want to delete it, just break the lease in the portal or use [`az storage blob lease break`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/lease?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-lease-break)

My test command(I specifie the duration of the lease with 15 seconds):

```
az storage blob lease acquire --blob-name "azureProfile.txt"--container-name "testdel" --account-key "accountkey" --account-name "storagename" --lease-duration "15"
az storage blob delete-batch --source "testdel" --account-key "accountkey" --account-name "storagename"
```

[image]

It gives a warning, but it works fine on my side.

Check in the portal:

[image]

Comment: Nice idea. But as I know there is no command for batch lease, right?

Comment: I want to reserve slightly above 400